# E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead

Tags: linux, ubuntu

I'm using **Ubuntu 14.04**. I have tried to modify the server in **software and updates** and failed. So, when I try to make update with  `sudo apt-get update` I got this error:

```
W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/ripps818/coreavc/ubuntu/dists/trusty/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found
W: Failed to fetch http://ubuntu.mirror.tn/dists/trusty/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found
W: Failed to fetch http://ubuntu.mirror.tn/dists/trusty/universe/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found
W: Failed to fetch http://ubuntu.mirror.tn/dists/trusty/restricted/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found
W: Failed to fetch http://ubuntu.mirror.tn/dists/trusty/multiverse/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found
W: Failed to fetch http://ubuntu.mirror.tn/dists/trusty/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found
W: Failed to fetch http://ubuntu.mirror.tn/dists/trusty/universe/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found
W: Failed to fetch http://ubuntu.mirror.tn/dists/trusty/restricted/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found
W: Failed to fetch   http://ubuntu.mirror.tn/dists/trusty/multiverse/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found

E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

any help please ?

Comment: Those sites don't exist (type them into your browser). Check http://releases.ubuntu.com/trusty/ if you want to add mirrors from Ubuntu, but why aren't you adding Debian repositories? What exactly do you want to get?

Comment: @kabanus  how can i add Debian repositories? . I am still a newbie in using ubuntu

Comment: I though you were on Debian because of the tag. Please edit your question to say you're on Ubuntu, and what package specifically are you looking for that wasn't in the default. Please go here to see how to properly edit source file: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Repositories/CommandLine

Comment: @kabanus I don't want to add repositories in sources.list .I only wanted to update my ubuntu and I didn't understand why I got this error.

Comment: The problem is obviously the server you modified, can't help without knowing what you're trying to do. Go back to the original server if you just want updates.

Comment: @kabanus I forgot the name of the old server how can I go back to it ?

Comment: Sorry I forget. I thought there was a 'fastest detected' option. Try googling Ubuntu or asking on their forums.

Answer (score 24):

Try this in the following order:

```
sudo su 
cd /var/lib/apt/lists/
rm -fr *
cd /etc/apt/sources.list.d/
rm -fr *
cd /etc/apt
sudo cp sources.list sources.list.old
sudo cp sources.list sources.list.tmp
sed 's/ubuntuarchive.hnsdc.com/us.archive.ubuntu.com/' sources.list.tmp | sudo tee sources.list
sudo rm sources.list.tmp*
apt-get clean
apt-get update
```